# sharing google docs to multiple drive folders

Tags: google-workspace

I am a highschool teacher using GSuite for education. I am looking for a user friendly way to share a google doc (or any type of document) to up to 90 Drive folders at once.

Shift+Z enables me to share the document without creating a copy and moving it to a different folder, which is convenient, but it can only be done one folder at a time. Too long.

Is there an API or any other solution that can help me with this issue? Google's help center referred me to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create one new folder, share it with all the recipants OR use the link sharing feature and send out an email with all of the people included.

OR

If you really need to add it to every single folder, then record and make a macro and repeat the steps until you have it all added.

As of now, there is no current simple and easy solution that Google has added that allows the feature of automatically duplicating the same document or placing the same document in multiple folders at one time.

You could potentially try out the 2 solutions that I mentioned above, or try to talk Google developers into adding a feature that allows the adding of the same document in multiple folders simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I never programmed a macro outside of MS Word... How would that work?

Comment: use this video for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOa6nL839YE, or search for a 3rd party macro recorder software. also would appreciate an answer acceptance if you found my answer helpful.